# Comparar registro atual com registro anterior em laço/loop

Tags: php, lógica

#### Cenário

Vamos supor que tenho 100 registros em **um BD qualquer**.

```
ID | PESSOA | CARRETO | ENDERECO | DISTANCIA
1  |   A    |    C10  |    XX    |    20
2  |   B    |    C20  |    XY    |    25
3  |   D    |    C50  |    XZ    |    19
4  |   D    |    C50  |    XZ    |    19
5  |   F    |    C10  |    XW    |    27
...
...
```

A partir de uma query, **vou gerar um Array com todos estes registros**, e enquanto faço o `fetch`, eu preciso verificar algumas condições, **comparando o registro anterior do registro corrente**:

- `ID` do reg. anterior `=` `ID` do reg. corrente -1
- `PESSOA` do reg. anterior `=` `PESSOA` do reg. corrente
- `CARRETO` do reg. anterior `=` `CARRETO` do reg. corrente
- `ENDERECO` do reg. anterior `=` `ENDERECO` do reg. corrente
- `DISTANCIA` do reg. anterior `=` `DISTANCIA` do reg. corrente

Exemplo:

```
ID | PESSOA | CARRETO | ENDERECO | DISTANCIA
3  |   D    |    C50  |    XZ    |    19
4  |   D    |    C50  |    XZ    |    19
```

(*Se caso todas as condições forem verdadeiras, eu gravo o registro corrente com a `DISTANCIA = 0`*.)

---

#### Como fiz

No laço que faço o `fetch`, eu usei variáveis auxiliares para trazer e comparar o registro anterior verificar as condições, e gravar o atual no array:

```
// variáveis auxiliares:
$id_ant = null; // seto como null para a 1a comparação
$pes_ant; $car_ant; $end_ant; $dis_ant;

while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

   // verifico as condições
   if ($id_ant == $row['ID']-1 && $pes_ant == $row['PESSOA'] && $car_ant == $row['CARRETO'] && $end_ant == $row['ENDERECO'] && $dis_ant == $row['DISTANCIA'])
       $row['DISTANCIA'] == 0;

   // gravo o registro no array
   $array[] = $row;

   // seto cada variável para depois utilizar na comparação posterior
   $id_ant = $row['ID']; 
   $pes_ant = $row['PESSOA']; 
   $car_ant = $row['CARRETO']; 
   $end_ant = $row['ENDERECO']; 
   $dis_ant = $row['DISTANCIA'];
}
```

Exemplo como ficaria o registro `4` no array:

```
(
    [ID] => 4
    [PESSOA] => D
    [CARRETO] => C50
    [ENDERECO] => XZ
    [DISTANCIA] => 0
)
```

---

#### Dúvidas

- E se eu tivesse uma tabela com 100 colunas a serem comparadas? Teria que fazer tudo isso uma a uma ou **tem uma forma "automática"** de fazer isso?
- É vantagem eu fazer isso já no `fetch` ou **seria melhor jogar tudo para um Array**  e depois trabalhar nele? (pensando em desempenho)

Comment: Isso não seria coisa de um `select distinct` ? O que está a tentar fazer é ficar apenas com os que não são duplicados em todos os campos ?

Comment: @Isac, não, preciso de todos. A única diferença é tratar se a condição for verdadeira, a distância fica 0, mas o registro tem que ir também!

Comment: No `if` você está usando `=` no lugar de `==`.  E você precisa comparar todos os campos? Só o `id` e o nome da `pessoa` não seria suficiente?

Comment: @ThiagoMagalhães opa cara, essa do `=` foi falha de digitação! Preciso comparar vários, por isso já estou pensando lá na frente, se caso tiver que comparar 100 colunas, entende!? rs

Comment: Você poderia salvar tudo em uma array e depois percorrer usando foreach.. dessa forma você poderia usar uma lógica para percorrer os atributos e fazer a comparação.

Comment: @ThiagoMagalhães então cara, acho que você está dizendo da forma que o gabriel.pelegrina postou como resposta!? 

Comment: É uma forma. E sobre passar tudo para `array`, pensando em desempenho, o ganhou ou perda nesse caso seria minimo.

Comment: @ThiagoMagalhães Então. Mas eu fazer comparação direto no `fetch` é 1 passo. Gerar o Array e depois fazer `foreach`, seriam 2 passos. Se pegar um volume grande, acredito que seja considerável sim.

Comment: O passo de gerar uma `array` computacionalmente terá um tempo de `linear = f(n)`. Então irá consumir o tempo do seu `foreach` + `n`, onde `n` é a quantidade de resultados. Aumentar `1 n` considero pouco, se comparar com funções de `(n^2)` e `(2^n)`, por exemplo.

Comment: Não entendi. Se eu fizer o `fetch`para gerar o array, eu percorro por exemplo 10.000 registros. Depois meu `foreach` terá que percorrer novamente os 10.000 registros. Não é assim!?

Answer (score -1):

Tente o exemplo abaixo:

```
//$array são todos os resultados da query ($result->fetch_all() )

if(count($array) > 1) { //verifica se existem mais de 1 item no array

  foreach ($array as $key => $atual) { //percorre o resultado da query

    if ($key > 0) { //compara se não é o primeiro item, pois este não terá item anterior

        $keyAnterior = $key - 1; //armazena o indice do registro anterior


        $anterior = $array[$keyAnterior]; //pega o item anterior do array

        if ($anterior['id'] == ($atual['id'] - 1)) { //comparar os ids (esta comparação ocorre devido a regra solicitada)

            unset($atual['id'], $anterior['id']); //remove a "coluna" id dos dois valores pois este ja foi comparado acima


            $saoIguais = $anterior === $atual; //compara se as colunas restantes do item anterior e do item atual são identicas

            if($saoIguais){
                //as demais colunas são iguais entre os itens
            }else{
                //as demais colunas são diferentes
            }

        } else {
            //a validação do id anterior == (id atual -1) não é verdadeira
        }
    }
  }
}
```

**EDIT**

Utilizando o método fetch_assoc você pode tentar assim:

```
$anterior = null;
while ($row < $result->fetch_assoc()) { //percorre pelo resultado da query
    $atual = $row; //utilizada variavel auxiliar pois o indice id será excluido do array, e precisaremos dele na proxima iteração

    if(!is_null($anterior)) { //verifica se o anterior não é null | primeira iteração
        if ($anterior['id'] == ($atual['id']) - 1) { //verificação do id

            unset($anterior['id'], $atual['id']); //remove o indice do item anterior e do atual

            if ($atual == $anterior) { //compara os indices restantes (podem ter N indices)
                echo "São iguais";
            } else {
                echo "São diferentes";
            }
        }
    }

    $anterior = $row; //atribui a variavel auxiliar ao item anterior
}
```

**Resposta Dúvida 1: ** Sim, é possível comparar N indíces com o operador de igualdade ( == ou ===);

**Resposda Dúvida 2: ** De acordo com [php.net](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-all.php%20%22php.net) utilizar o método fetch_all() irá consumir mais memória pois retorna todas as linhas de uma só vez. Neste caso em específico você ainda precisa iterar cada linha com um loop, o que pode sim impactar na performance. No entanto, para resultados de poucas linhas é imperceptível.

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Seria bom explicar o que você fez...

Comment: Opa, vou editar

Comment: Olá Gabriel! Primeiramente agradeço sua resposta, entendi ela perfeitamente, gostei. Como você está usando o `array`, não teria como então já fazer isso direto no `fetch`? E gostaria de saber sobre a 2a questão, se é melhor fazer no `fetch` ou tratar no array como fez. ✌️

Comment: @rbz dá uma olhada no edit. Espero que ajude.

Answer (score -1):

Faça assim

```
<?PHP 
while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {

   // verifico as condições
   if ($id_ant == $row && $row['ID']==$id_ant['ID']-1){
    $array[] = $row;
   }
   $id_ant = $row;
}
?>
```